# CosmosDB: Enforce unique constraints

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, unique-constraint

Is it possible to enforce unique constraints on Azure CosmosDB's graph model? If I'm registering new users and need to ensure only unique email addresses/usernames/etc. are used, how can this be accomplished there?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your partitioning strategy you can use these values to enforce uniqueness either by using them in the partition key directly or by using them as an id inside of a known partition for your users.

Comment: Thanks. Partition key can repeat though, right? How would using them in the partition key directly be useful? Multiple records can have the same partition key. As for the id, email address/username/phone number values are most likely not as random as a GUID which means users won't be distributed evenly across physical partitions.

Comment: I was thinking maybe I could use a `lock` in my Web API method so that the signup API is single-threaded (assuming only one server handles this API). I have not tried this approach, but would that be a good solution? Unfortunately, with NoSQL dbs, app-side has to handle some data integrity logic.

Comment: However, with the abovesaid approach and knowing that CosmosDB is eventually consistent, I might get reads that are not up to date with writes. So, I'm not sure if using a `lock` can do the job reliably.

Answer (score -1):

We recently launched unique key support for Cosmos DB. This should work seamlessly for graph collections as well.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/unique-keys

Just, create a graph with desired unique key path. After that adding a vertex with the same unique key compared to an existing vertex, should fail.

Comment: That very article you link says "The Table API and Graph API do not support unique keys at this time." Is that information not up-to-date?

Comment: Jayanta, the article mentions unique keys are not available for graphs. Is the article incorrect?